# WooCommerce select x number of items from large group for single product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site where customers can order color samples with the following characteristics:

1. Select multiple colors from a list of over 100
2. First 3 choices are free
3. Each subsequent color choice will add 1 dollar to price of order

It does not seem appropriate in this case to make 100+ separate simple products for each color and bundle them (neither do we track inventory on samples) I just want customers to make their multiple choices in the context of one product called "Samples". I have looked at the [bundled products page docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/group-bundle-products-woocommerce/) and none of these seem appropriate for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think SO all is about programming and if you are getting stuck somewhere we can/try to help. But people should not post their entire project requirement here. We are not freelancers here.

Comment: I respect what you say, but stackoverflow is the de facto place to ask complicated woocommerce questions, as it is the place with the best responses. I think configuration or advice on strategy questions are fair game.

Comment: I am not asking someone to program anything for me btw, just asking for some direction.

Comment: Atleast you could have created variants(color) for products and tried to resolve and then posted the whole scenario. We can't see any effort there :(

Comment: I created attributes for all the colors, but this doesn't work because they are single select. So I am just asking if there is a better way other than creating 100+ single products (one for each color). I can't really move ahead until I can answer that question.

Comment: So you can think of this as a strategy question, and  I am sorry if you feel a programming strategy question is inappropriate, but I think it is fair game.

Comment: With each variation you can add multiple product... not in a single click surely but still you have to select color and select quantity for that color.

Comment: These are not variations, that is the problem. This product is "select x choices from same attribute group", one grouped product. I don't want to send users back to select a new sample every time on a new order.

Comment: You have to program for that... show every variation in same page with your coding.... show in checkboxes, take all the values and use woocommerce function  $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$quantity,$variation_id);

Comment: Ok, I will attempt something like that, thanks for the input I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a plugin and some custom code. The plugin is [here](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619), and the custom code counts the number of items in the grouping and modifies the price based on that number. In my case, I wanted each option to cost a dollar, but have the first 3 be free. I use a woo hook to change the price before adding it to the cart (this gets fired off when the add to cart button is clicked after selections are made):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $target_product_id = 9516; // my product ID

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key=>$value ) {
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
        if (count($value['tmdata']['tmcp_post_fields'])>=3){
            $value['data']->set_price($value['tm_epo_options_prices'] - 3);
            } elseif (count($value['tmdata']['tmcp_post_fields'])==2){
            $value['data']->set_price($value['tm_epo_options_prices'] - 2);
            } elseif (count($value['tmdata']['tmcp_post_fields'])==1){
             $value['data']->set_price($value['tm_epo_options_prices'] - 1);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that above code is calling data (tm_epo_options_prices) provided by the [plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619).